# c#: SQL Server Spatial Function: Polygon Rings Error on Some Records

Tags: c#, sql-server, geometry, spatial

I have a C# Console application which parses a .JSON file and inserts coordinates into a Geometry field of a SQL Server 2012 database. Everything was working fine except I am now finding that for *some* records I get an error:

```
 Message=24119: The Polygon input is not valid because the start and end points of the exterior ring are not the same. Each ring of a polygon must have the same start and end points.
```

Here is relevant C# code:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ShapeGeom", System.Data.SqlDbType.Udt));
cmd.Parameters["@ShapeGeom"].UdtTypeName = "Geometry";               
cmd.Parameters["@ShapeGeom"].Value = GetGeometryFromText("POLYGON((" + coords_final_formatted + "))");
```

and the `GetGeometryFromText` function is as:

```
 public static SqlGeometry GetGeometryFromText(String pText)
    {
        System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlString ss = new SqlString(pText);
        SqlChars sc = new SqlChars(ss);           
        return SqlGeometry.STPolyFromText(sc, 3857);

    }
```

I can see that the `coords_final_formatted` variable for some records indeed have mismatching very first coordinates with the very last coordinates; and hence, the polygon is not 'closing'.  I have done some researches and some suggested that I append a `MakeValid()` to the above code but that made no difference. Am I out of luck? I don't know if I should really 'massage' the data to insert the final coordinates to match the very first coordinates?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I **think** I got it: The data was probably sloppy: In ArcMAP the polygons were not drawn to 'close' them and hence the very last set of coordinates in the Rings did not match the beginning one.

I have 'massaged' the data in C# so that if the last element of a Ring does not match its first element then programmatically copy the first element to become the last element. The data now makes to SQL Server and looks okay to me. I will probably convey to the ArcMap authors to close the polygons.

HTH.

*** Not really going to work--get an error in ArcMAP when I look at the data from the database: One or more lines/polygons are insercting***